# SQL Server Binary(16) in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with some columns: 1. nvarchar(30), 2. int, 3. binary(16).
Now, In c# I have a class that represents those columns:

```
public string aaa { get; set; }
public int bbb { get; set; }
```

And how do I write the third one (binary(16)) ?

Answer (score 10):

`Binary` column is commonly mapped to byte arrays:

```
public byte[] ThirdColumn {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!!

Comment: You can find an overview here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx